# Writing One to one relationship using Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

How to write a `one-to-one--or-zero` relationship using fluent api? Can someone help me out correct what i have written. I am not sure if its correct.

The scenario : One Student Can have one or zero Address.

## Student Model

```
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public Address Address{ get; set; }
```

## Address Model

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Street{ get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    public Student Student { get; set; }
```

What I tried:

```
        builder.HasOne(u => u.Address)
        .WithOne(b => b.Student)
        .HasForeignKey<Address>(b => b.StudentId);
```

Comment: This is EF core 2.1.

Comment: `StudentId` in your **Address Model** should be declared as an int.

Comment: @vinicius.ras Yes. corrected.

Comment: Your solution btw is perfectly fine. The solution from the accepted answer is also fine, but **not mandatory**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case of `one-to-one--or-zero` relationship you don't need additional `PrimaryKey` along with the `ForeignKey` in dependent table. `Primarykey` of the `Principle` table will also be the `PrimaryKey` and `ForeignKey` of the dependent table at the same time.

So write your `Address` model class as follows:

```
public class Address
{
   public int StudentId { get; set; } // Here StudentId is the PrimaryKey and ForeignKey at the same time.
   public string Street{ get; set; }

   public Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the `Fluent API` configuration:

```
public class AddressConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Address>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Address> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(u => u.StudentId)
        builder.HasOne(u => u.Student)
               .WithOne(b => b.Address)
               .HasForeignKey<Address>(b => b.StudentId);
    }
}
```

Comment: OP is not "close to the solution". Both one-to-one with Shared PK (yours) and FK (OPs) are supported by EF Core.

Comment: Thank you! But Shared PK makes it more sensible!

Answer (score 0):

To configure a `one-to-zero-or-one` relationship between the Student and Address entities with fluent api you can use `HasOptional(s => s.Address)` method like

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
            .HasOptional(s => s.Address) // Address property is optional in Student entity
            .WithRequired(ad => ad.Student); // Student property is required
```

Comment: This is for EF not for EF Core!